# Why a PostgreSQL query ran 3 days as a scheduled Windows task?

Tags: windows, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I have a Windows scheduled task which has to run a batch file. The batch file is PostgreSQL query to insert some data. What we saw from the logs is that the task was triggered & got a process id too. But the task has no other update in the logs & kept on running for 3 days. We are not able to find the reason for it to run for 3 days. Also when the task was run, no user had logged in. In a similar case we got return code 1 when we replicated. Anybody has faced similar issues?

UPDATE:

```
psql -h localhost -d dbname -p 5432 -U postgres -w -f pathToSqlQueryFile
```

The sql query file contains a sql query with case statements to calculate working hours. The password is provided in the pgpass file.

Comment: Please share some code, especially from the batch file

Comment: @kritzel_sw Updated the question with the contents of the batch file

Comment: It probably waited (or is waiting) for a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem which was in our **batch file**.
The line **cmd \k** which keeps the command prompt open was the reason the task was running until it timedout